# How to do an AS3 to HTML5 conversion with external AS files

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I have a rather large and complicated Flash project that I've been tasked with converting to html5 and javaScript. The main issue I am encountering (aside from the myriad of unsupported features) is that it is heavily reliant on external .as files and I am not sure how to approach it.  Everything I have found suggests manually re-scripting in javaScript but I do not have the time or budget for that and of course I am looking for an easier and softer way to get this done.

When I "Convert to HTML5 from AS3 document formats" in Flash CC are the external .as files converted and compiles as well?  I cant tell as I am a total noob and wandering through this nearly blind with ignorance.

Thanks in advance for the help and guidance

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens?

Comment: Have you tried the "Convert to HTML5 from AS3 document formats" option yet? The easiest way is to try it and see if you get a working application/animation as a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert in this (because I don't use the feature), but from my understanding:

The convert to HTML5/Canvas/WebGL is not for code-oriented projects, but is designed for `timeline` projects.

Sadly (as is the case for most development), there isn't going to be some magic bullet tool that will sprinkle pixie dust on your project and make it exactly the same but HTML5/JS

The convert tool is great for moving your display assets from Flash to Canvas, but you'll need to rewrite at least some of the code most likely.

[CreateJS](http://createjs.com/) is a good JS Canvas library that mimics much of the display logic in Flash/AS3. (it's what flash actually uses when you output HTML5 I believe).   Manually converting AS3 to JS isn't actually that difficult as they are both ECMAScript based.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it looks like I've got alot of work to do!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try [Haxe](http://haxe.org/), That is a cross-plateform language very similar to AS3. You write your code once and then, you can compile it to many plateform including HTML5.
There are some tools to help you converting your .as files to .hx (.hx are Haxe files), even if you'll have to modify some things, maybe it will be faster than re-coding everything in JS.

But as you sayed, there are a lot of unsupported features in HTML5 (compared to AS3) so there is no magical solution for your problem. :)

I did many conversion from AS3 to Haxe (an then compiled for HTML5 target) and i can tell that, this is not too difficul for very small projects. But of course if you have a lot of files and a lot of line of code that may be harder.